# Read with python and django an array of input fields

Tags: python, arrays, django, post, request

i'm tring to read from request.POST an array of fields

```
<input type="text" name="arrayfield[]" /><br />
<input type="text" name="arrayfield[]" /><br />
<input type="text" name="arrayfield[]" /><br />
<input type="text" name="arrayfield[]" /><br />
<input type="text" name="arrayfield[]" /><br />
<input type="text" name="arrayfield[]" /><br />
<input type="text" name="arrayfield[]" /><br />
```

if i use print(request.POST) i get that output

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['p0GWUzgXEEYOTI1710vTsUAPrjUUv5NpqlVCGU7Oq1zw4LWA20d222q1aE8QvlIg'], 'username': ['Oscurodrago'],  'birthday': ['1988-04-16'], 'arrayfield[]': ['try', 'tyey', 'egr', '', 'tyr', '', ''], 'edit': ['Modifica']}>
```

but when i try get it with request.POST.get('arrayfield[]','') dosen't work
what i have to do?

Answer (score 1):

i found that solution

arraylist = request.POST.getlist('arrayfield[]')

Answer (score -1):

To use the Post method, you have to make sure your form has {% csrf_token %} if not it won't work.

```
    <div>
     <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input />
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: yes i know i used that in template...
however i founs a solution request.POST.getlist('arrayfield[]')